# How to get a dot exactly in between two vertical bars

Tags: punctuation

How can I get the dot between to vertical bars exactly in the middle, just like in this picture:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
\vert.\vert
\lvert.\rvert
\|.\|
\vert\dot\vert
```

But this yields mostly to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: HORIZONTAL CENTERING:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\vert\,.\,\vert$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `\,` has been added as space padding and can be removed or augmented.

ORIGINAL ANSWER: VERTICAL CENTERING

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\vert\cdot\vert$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That dot floats in the middle. I would like it to be lower, just as our usual 'punctuation' dot.

Comment: @ShaVuklia So you mean horizontal mill rather than vertical middle?

Comment: Horizontal middle, vertical low?

Comment: @ShaVuklia See my EDIT

Comment: I think you should remove the second `\,`. So this works: `\vert\,.\vert`.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is hacking though, but I guess it will do for now!

Comment: @ShaVuklia You must have something else going on in your document setup, as my code produces my picture, and removing the right hand `\,` as you suggest destroys the symmetry of my result.  Perhaps you need to post a full, but minimal example in your question.

Comment: I've realised it's a Math Jax problem. If I type `\vert.\vert` in Overleaf for instance, then the dot is nicely in the middle. However, if I use Math Jax in the mathematical forum of StackExchange, then the dot isn't centered. Thanks for the help anyhow!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your period has a non-standard math code and is configured as math punctuation character. This adds additional space at the right of the dot.
This insertion can be avoided by putting the period in a subformula using curly braces: `{.}`. These curly braces around the dot are also needed, if the dot is used as decimal separator (or as digit group separator).

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Standard math code of the period:
  \[
    {\color{blue} \vert.\vert \quad 123.456}
    \quad (\verb|\vert. \quad 123.456|)
  \]
\item Changing math code of period from \verb|\mathord| to \verb|\mathpunct|:
  \mathcode`\.=\numexpr\mathcode`\. + "6000\relax
  \[
    \verb|\mathcode`\.=\numexpr\mathcode`\. + "6000\relax|
  \]
\item Period as punctuation character:
  \[
    {\color{blue} \vert.\vert \quad 123.456}
    \quad (\verb|\vert.\vert \quad 123.456|)
  \]
\item Fix by putting the dot in curly braces:
  \[
    {\color{blue} \vert{.}\vert \quad 123{.}456}
    \quad (\verb|\vert{.}\vert \quad 123{.}456|)
  \]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! That solved the problem:) (I feel bad for accepting your answer instead of the previous one which I've already accepted, so I hope that a simple up-vote will do too!)

Comment: @ShaVuklia You can unaccept my answer and select Heiko's superior answer instead.  Then I will just delete mine.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no, because you helped me out too. I think this is a good compromise!